# jQuery draggable into sortable only works after sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm experiencing problems with a simple combination of a Draggable and Sortable: initially, the dragging does not work and I do not get a receive callback. Only *after* I have done a sort (i.e. change the position of things in #workarea), can I drag new things into it.

Somehow it seems as if the sortable needs to be 'initialized' before it accepts draggables. My code, in a simplified version:

```
$(".element_draggable").draggable({
    zIndex: 2,
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '#workarea'});

$("#workarea").sortable({
    receive: function() {alert('received');}
});
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: I was using $("#content").slideDown('fast'); on the div in which it all happened. Apparently that makes things more difficult ;-)